# initializing Redis variables

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, redis

I am locally debugging an app that uses Redis, and because Redis doesn't save variables from one start-up to the next (for example, if I start my Redis server, and I 'SET total 0', and I then start-up the server again, 'total' is now nil). Because I want to initialize 5 variables at the start of every Redis connection, I am wondering if there is a way to write a bash script that initializes them for me. I tried to do:

```
redis-server # Starts Server
redis-cli # Starts command line interface
SET total 0
SET str hello
```

All in a bash script, but I get the error:

```
SET: command not found
```

Is there any way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: AWS Redis doesn't allow `save` directive in config?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
redis-cli "set total 5"
```

or

```
echo "set total 5" | redis-cli
```

or, in `bash` shell

```
redis-cli <<< "set total 5"
```

Or:

```
 redis-cli <<EOF
 set total 5
 set str hello
 EOF
```